# Microsoft Outlook Sensitivity level: Normal vs Personal vs Private vs Confidential

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

`Microsoft Outlook` provides the option to mark the `sensitivity level` of any message. The options are Normal, Personal, Private, and Confidential. Whilst the default value is Normal.

[image]

What is the difference between all these sensitivity labels?

I know and read at [Mark your email as Normal, Personal, Private, or Confidential](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mark-your-email-as-normal-personal-private-or-confidential-4a76d05b-6c29-4a0d-9096-71784a6b12c1):

> A message that has a sensitivity level of Private isn't forwarded or redirected by a recipient’s Inbox rules.

Meaning, if a message is marked private any delegates to the sender's mailbox are not able to view the message.
However, still can not figure out the difference between confidential and personal. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the article you provided, the sensitivity level is used to help recipients know your intentions and they can take actions on the message that you want to, except that "A message that has a sensitivity level of Private isn't forwarded or redirected by a recipient’s Inbox rules".
[image]

In my submission, setting these levels is just a way for the sender to remind the recipient, so that the recipient can understand the particularity of a specific message when receiving it.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.